# Python creating a new dataframe with list of unique dates as index

Tags: python

I have dateframe with index as df.index =

```
2016-08-01 06:45:00    
2016-08-01 07:00:00    
2016-08-01 07:15:00    
.
.
2018-03-28 11:30:00    
2018-03-28 11:45:00    
2018-03-28 12:00:00
```

I want to create a new dataframe that it will have only unique dates as

new_df.index =

```
2016-08-01
2016-08-02
.
.
2018-03-28
2018-03-29
```

So, how to create a new dataframe with unique dates as index?

Answer (score 0):

There is a build-in collection [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?#set) in Python, that have only unique elements. You can do something like it:

`new_data = sorted(list(set(old_data)))`

If you want to crop out time in your datetime lines, you can modify this code with generators:

`new_data = sorted(list(set([elem[:10] for elem in old_data])))`

Note, that if you have some info linked with your datetimes (like values in dict with datetime keys), you must handle elements removal before doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not provided any data I will assume it is not important.

Your first `DataFrame` appears to have a `DatetimeIndex` and it appears you want to convert it to a `PeriodIndex`.  You can do this to get the unique days with `df.resample(rule='D').asfreq()`.  Docs are [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html)

Comment: it is giving list of dates for each row: `print(new_df.index.to_period(freq='D')) 
Out[106]: 
PeriodIndex(['2016-08-01', '2016-08-01', '2016-08-01', '2016-08-01',
             '2016-08-01', '2016-08-01', '2016-08-01', '2016-08-01',
             '2016-08-01', '2016-08-01',
             ...
             '2018-03-28', '2018-03-28', '2018-03-28', '2018-03-28',
             '2018-03-28', '2018-03-28', '2018-03-28', '2018-03-28',
             '2018-03-28', '2018-03-28'],
            dtype='period[D]', length=26644, freq='D')`

Comment: With your new code now I have a output: `Index([2016-08-01, 2016-08-02, 2016-08-03, 2016-08-05, 2016-08-06, 2016-08-07,
       2016-08-08, 2016-08-09, 2016-08-10, 2016-08-11,
       ...
       2018-03-19, 2018-03-20, 2018-03-21, 2018-03-22, 2018-03-23, 2018-03-24,
       2018-03-25, 2018-03-26, 2018-03-27, 2018-03-28],
      dtype='object', length=601)`. But how to get only `['2016-08-01', '2016-08-02', 
       ...
        '2018-03-28']`. I mean, i want it to be a string. So I can use it for other purpose.

Comment: @Msquare I think it's best if you update the question with exactly what you're looking for or start a new question.